# REACT: Undesirable arrows inside html <select>

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jsx

SOLUTION: as @prasanth sugested me, I created a fake dropdown, a placeholder.
Both the fake and the real dropdown shares a

```
style={{"display":countryChange?"":"none"}}
```

obviously the real one is inverted with the fake one. Once i ping the api, I hide the real one and show the fake one. Once the api returns with value, i write the state so the fake disapears. Worked like a charm.

I'm new to react, and trying to make a dynamic dropdown based on an api call. I have a local api in "/avaliable_countries" which returns {countries:"Brasil" and "United States"}. I want those two fields to create the `<options>` dynamcially, and it is almost working as intended.

The problemis: In the first click, I got this weird arrows. If I click out/again or two times, then it becomes normal.

no click:

[image]

first click, weird arrows(and using the weird arrows  can navigate between the two countries):

[image]

Clicking in/out or two times in a row, becomes the desired output:

[image]

Without any CSS(weird arrows still here):
[image]

The code:

```
import React,{useState} from 'react';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import './styles.css';
import api from '../../services/api';

export default function Signup(){
    var [countriesObj, setCountriesObj] = useState(<option>Select your country</option>)
    async function getAvaliableCountries(){
        setCountriesObj();
        try{
            const response = await api.get(
                'avaliable_countries','',
                {headers: {
                    'Content-Type':"application/json",   
                }        
                });
                window.arrayOfCountries = response.data.countries ; 
                let countriesList = (window.arrayOfCountries.map((data) =>
                <option>
                    {data}
                </option>)               
            );
            setCountriesObj(countriesList);
        }catch(err){
            alert('Error obtaining the list of countries.')
        }
    }


    return(
        <div className="wrapper">
            <div id="formContent">        
            <h2 className="inactive underlineHover"> 
            <Link to="/">Sign In</Link>
            </h2>
            <h2 className="active">                
            Sign Up
            </h2>     
            <form>
                <select
                onClick={getAvaliableCountries}
                name="animal"
                className="form-control">
                {countriesObj}
                </select>    
            </form>    
            <div id="formFooter">                   
            </div>        
        </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually not React related and you can use simple CSS to remove the arrow:

```
select {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;       /* Remove default arrow */
    background-image: url(...);   /* Add custom arrow */
}
```

For more information you can see the original answer here: [How do I style a  dropdown with only CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895476/how-do-i-style-a-select-dropdown-with-only-css)

Answer (score 3):

You could do like this .Component use with in array not a good practise.so extract the component with `Array#map` on render .And dont forget use the [`key`](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html) on map child `options`

**Updated :**
    load the array on component mount instead of click . try this [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) with in react

**[Demo code](https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-leftpad-77o5p?file=/src/App.js)**

```
import React,{useState,useEffect} from 'react';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import './styles.css';
import api from '../../services/api';
export default function Signup() {
  var [countriesObj, setCountriesObj] = useState(['select'])
      async function getAvaliableCountries() {
        setCountriesObj();
        try {
          const response = await api.get(
            'avaliable_countries', '', {
              headers: {
                'Content-Type': "application/json"
              }
            }
          );
          window.arrayOfCountries = response.data.countries;
          let countriesList = response.data.countries
          setCountriesObj(countriesList);
        } catch (err) {
          alert('Error obtaining the list of countries.')
        }
      }
    useEffect(()=>{
             getAvaliableCountries()
          },[])

    return(
        <div className="wrapper">
            <div id="formContent">        
            <h2 className="inactive underlineHover"> 
            <Link to="/">Sign In</Link>
            </h2>
            <h2 className="active">                
            Sign Up
            </h2>     
            <form>
       <select name="animal" className="form-control">
        {countriesObj.map(data => (
          <option key={data}>{data}</option>
        ))}
      </select>
            </form>    
            <div id="formFooter">                   
            </div>        
        </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Just copied your code and it gave the exact same output with the godamn arrows!

Comment: @RoniAntonio .check the updated code and [demo here](https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-leftpad-77o5p?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Hi @prashanth, even in your demo i was able to reproduce the godamn arrows. If you click on the dropdown, which will trigger the function, and then wait the 3 seconds, the arrows will appear.

Also, I really need that the dropdown have a default value ('click here to select your country'), so the api call will be triggered once the user clicks

Comment: Also, in another parts from my code one dropdown will have a list of options based on the value that the user selected in another dropdown (I select the country India, then the States dropdown have all india States). So the solution that I'm looking could not rely on component mount, it should update during runtime :(

Comment: @RoniAntonio .its not good for each time click to load .That why you  are getting  select arrow problem also. For component mount  finish the execution before the  select will shown .its depend on your internet and server speed .if you need a state name you just pic the value on change event of countries select button . or else you need to make up with some placeholder component . click the placeholder load api call then show the select button

Answer (score 0):

Kindly check your css and there must some css like "content: '<>';" which is crreating issue for this type of style.
It's not because of react and it's css issue so kindly check css (style.css) of select.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But I don't think that it is realted to the css, I removed every single css and the weird arrows are still there!

Comment: Could you please tell the browser and version

Comment: Chrome, 81.0.4044.138